# Yarn v3.0.2 Why do not install the node_modules folder ? Need to run npm install after the yarn's commands?

Tags: yarnpkg

Why Yarn v3.0.2 doesn't install the node_modules folder with all packages? So i need to run the command npm install after the yarn's commands? Every time i'm using yarn 3 to handle my dependencies i need to run npm command install too?

Answer (score 17):

try to add this code `nodeLinker: node-modules` in `.yarnrc.yml` file

see [node_modules is missing after successful yarn install](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5500#issuecomment-1221456246)

Comment: As this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75567577/ mentions, and looking at the linked issue in your answer, it seems there's a typo. Could you fix that, if it is indeed a typo?

Comment: This will surely force yarn to create node_modules folder, but it is better not to do this, let yarn use Plug'n'Play strategy instead.

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify something that confused me, you need to add `nodeLinker: node-modules` with a dash and not an underscore according to documentation.

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker

I can't leave a comment on the top post above to mention this...

Answer (score 3):

Because Yarn to solve the node_modules problem unveiled the Plug'n'Play strategy for Node.

https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp